# Keycloak returns 403 after login

Tags: java, spring-security, keycloak

I have a Keycloak server and my web application. When I try login into the app, always Keycloak returns a 403 - Forbidden.

This is my configuration from the web project,

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 38080
keycloak.realm=FocusocKeycloak
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=login-provider-web
keycloak.public-client=false
keycloak.credentials.secret=XXXX
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0] = USER
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0] = /*

# Turn off the logs
logging.level.root=OFF
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=OFF
spring.main.banner-mode=OFF
```

**keycloak.json**

```
{
  "realm": "FocusocKeycloak",
  "auth-server-url": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "login-app",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "XXXX"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Here is the configuration of the Client,
[image]

And I only have registered the role ROLE_USER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It was a little mistake in the configure method in the config class, where I didn't change

```
...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("user");
    }
...
```

and It has to be

```
...
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/home")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER");
    }
...
```

Now the error 403 doesn't appear, but now the /home page doesn't show.